# UITableView/Dynamic Prototype/Custom Cell - First Cell is always bigger than the remaining cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have placed a UITableView onto my viewcontroller.

```
Content = Dynamic Prototypes
Prototype Cells = 1
Cell Style = Custom
```

The cell has a UIImageView within it, which fills the bounds of the cell

The UImageView displays each image in my array. For example, when the app is run, cell 1 = displays image1.png, cell2 = displays image2.png, etc

However whenever I do this, the first cell is always bigger than the rest. I have tried messing about with the content mode, and cell size options, but the first cell is always bigger

As an example, see the screenshot below. Cell 1 is clearly bigger than cell 2, cell 3, and cell 4, even though its the exact same image in each cells

[image: sample image]

My requirement is to specify the height of the cell, and then the viewcontroller will display a portion of that image within the cell, that fits. Of course it won't show the whole image, since the image size exceeds the cell size, but that's fine

All cells need to be the same size

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard you have to set the tableView's cell height and the height for the prototype cell.

Comment: Shouldn't whatever is set automatically apply itself to all cells? Why is the first cell bigger than the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure your image is aligned with aspect Fit and set the height of Cell's content View.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 100

}
```